# How many Timelines to use in a Javafx karaoke game?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

So I suppose this is a question about efficiency. I'm making a karaoke style game, where 'notes' are animated across the screen and you have to press the correct button at the correct time. The code to add a note so far is this:

```
private void addNote(Pane pane){
        int lineNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 3);
        Circle note = new Circle();
        note.setRadius(10);
        note.setCenterX(500 + (50*lineNumber));
        pane.getChildren().add(note);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(new Duration(5000),
                        new KeyValue(note.layoutYProperty(), (400), Interpolator.EASE_BOTH),
                        new KeyValue(note.opacityProperty(), 0, Interpolator.EASE_OUT)
                )
        );
        timeline.play();
    }
```

Each note has it's own timeline. When running this method every 0.1 seconds my GPU hits around 60% useage (from the normal 20% or so on the application). I estimate there is about 30 small black circles being animated down the screen and faded out. This seems like enormous GPU useage for such simple shapes and a simple animation.

So I wanted to ask anyone - is this extreme usage a result of the amount of shapes being animated at once, or that fact that I have 30+ timelines being run at the same time? And whether there is anything I can do to reduce the useage here. Maybe there's a way to do it with a single timeline?

Edit: I've tried caching the circles with the cache hint SPEED - and that seems to knock of about 15% useage. Still would like more if possible!

Comment: Provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that demos this problem.